# how to add a sign between each letter in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, loops

I have a task, in which i have to write a function called `accum`, which transforms given string into something like this:

```
Accumul.Accum("abcd");    // "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
Accumul.Accum("RqaEzty"); // "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
Accumul.Accum("cwAt");    // "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

So far I only converted each letter to uppercase and... Now that I am writing about it, I think it could be easier for me to - firstly multiply the number of each letter and then add a dash there... Okay, well let's say I already multiplied the number of them(I will deal with it later) and now I need to add the dash. I tried several manners to solve this, including: for and foreach(and now that I think of it, I can't use foreach if I want to add a dash after multiplying the letters) with String.Join, String.Insert or something called StringBuilder with Append(which I don't exactly understand) and it does nothing to the string.

One of those loops that I tried was:

```
for (int letter = 0; letter < s.Length-1; letter += 2) {
      if (letter % 2 == 0) s.Replace("", "-");
     }
```

and

```
for (int letter = 0; letter < s.Length; letter++) {
      return String.Join(s, "-");
     }
```

The second one returns "unreachable code" error. What am I doing wrong here, that it does nothing to the string(after uppercase convertion)? Also, is there any method to copy each letter, in order to increase the number of them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say `string.join` can be used as long as an enumerable is created instead of a foreach. Since the string itself is enumerable, you can use the Linq select overload which includes an index:

```
var input = "abcd";
var res = string.Join("-", input.Select((c,i) => Char.ToUpper(c) + new string(Char.ToLower(c),i)));
```

(Assuming each char is unique or can be used. e.g. "aab" would become "A-Aa-Bbb")

Explanation:
The `Select` extension method takes a lambda function as parameter with `c` being a char and `i` the index. The lambda returns an uppercase version of the char (`c`) folowed by a string of the lowercase char of the index length (`new string(char,length)`), (which is an empty string for the first index). Finally the `string.join` concatenates the resulting enumeration with a `-` between each element.

Comment: Ah, that worked for me perfectly fine. Another time where i stubbornely still tried to use loop, but... Well I didn't find anywhere "Select" method. I mean just didn't know about it(sometimes if you want to find anything in microsoft C# reference, you have to dig it up). However, please explain, why exactly in "Join" the dash goes first, yet later it fits how it is supposed to fit. Is it just syntax for "Join"? Also, could you explain how does Select here work? Because I got the basic meaning, however I don't understand the purpose of "c" and "i" there and their exact syntax in this line

Comment: @Coerdringer If this is for your homework and you haven't seen Linq in your class, I would advise you use whatever your teacher showed you guys. You might end up in a sticky situation if he asks you to explain this or to recreate something similar. But that doesn't mean you should't inform yourself more on [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: The `Select` with index (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) is easily missed because it's an overload of the regular select. `(c,i)` form the parameters of the (lambda) function, where the first parameters (`c`) is the character and the second the index. In all `string.join` versions (this one is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx ), the separator is the first parameter given, followed by (in this case) the enumerable information

Comment: @CNuts Well it isn't my homework, since I am learning C# only as a self-study. I am taking tasks from codewars(this was one of these). And thank you for the hint to study Linq, as far as i see it will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
string result = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    char c = s[i];
    result += char.ToUpper(c);
    result += new String(char.ToLower(c), i);
    if (i < s.Length - 1)
    {
        result += "-";
    }
}
```

It will be better to use `StringBuilder` instead of strings concatenation, but this code can be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, which means that you cannot modify them once you created them. It means that `Replace` function return a new string that you need to capture somehow:

```
s = s.Replace("x", "-");
```

you currently are not assigning the result of the Replace method anywhere, that's why you don't see any results

Answer (score 0):

For the future, the best way to approach problems like this one is not to search for the code snippet, but write down step by step algorithm of how you can achieve the expected result in plain English or some other pseudo code, e.g.

**Given I have input string 'abcd' which should turn into output string 'A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd'.**

1. Copy first character 'a' from the input to Buffer.
2. Store the index of the character to Index.
3. If Buffer has only one character make it Upper Case.
4. If Index is greater then 1 trail Buffer with Index-1 lower case characters.
5. Append dash '-' to the Buffer.
6. Copy Buffer content to Output and clear Buffer.
7. Copy second character 'b' from the input to Buffer.
8. ...
   etc.

Aha moment often happens on the third iteration. Hope it helps! :)